# Android XML layout - Setting an attribute to the value of another attribute of a widget

Tags: android, binding

I would like to set a custom attribute (in this case, app:unfocusColor) to the value of another attribute (e.g app:cardBackgroundColor), is this possible?
I try the below method, but has error

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
   .....
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:unfocusColor="@{app:cardBackgroundColor}"
   >
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can!

for example

create res/valuesmyattr.xml

use this code as content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="myatt">
        <attr name="viewName" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

in your activity use this code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {


        int id =attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android","id",-1);

        if (id == R.id.specialViewId) {
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.myatt);
            String viewName = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.myatt_viewName);
        }

        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
```

and your view should lookalike this

```
<TextView
    app:number="1"
    android:id="@+id/specialViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"></TextView>
```

finally if you want use this with out overriding activity you can use LayourInflaterFactory interface

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. But that look quite involved. In my example, I just want app:unfocusColor set to the value of app:cardBackgroundColor attribute of the same widget. So is there a simple way to do this, without any logic code or resource.xml involved?

Comment: android card view dose not have app:focusColor and  app:unfocusColor attributes and  i don't know what you are trying do with the "@{app:cardBackgroundColor}"  its looks like data binding but i think you are using it wrong way see the link  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Actually the app:focusColor and app:unfocusColor is indeed my custom attribute, which is associated to a static method in a class. Nevertheless, I trying to set a value to the app:unfocusColor, which happen to be the same value as the app:cardBackGroundColor.   So , i was thinking if there is any way to avoid duplicate the values for both attribute

Comment: I update my example to remove away the app:focusColor, since it is unrelevant to my query.    Although in my example, i am using app:unfocusColor, but it can actually be any existing attribute whose value is a color.

Comment: for your question " i was thinking if there is any way to avoid duplicate the values for both attribute" Yes , you can declare variable in android layout xmls and for this search about data binding in android or go to the link in my previous comment